# Como passar uma função da classe App para outro arquivo (React)

Tags: react, react-native

Quero fazer meu modal fechar e voltar ao menu criado no arquivo App.

```
import './styles/menu.css'
import  Calculator  from './Pages/Calculator'
import { useState } from 'react'

function App() {
  const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState(0)
  const ModalVerification = () => {
    if (openModal == 1) return <Calculator openModal={openModal} modalVerification={ModalVerification}/>
    else {
          return  <div className='wholeContent'>
                    <header className='menuImage'>
                      <img className='image' src='/src/assets/mathWorld.png'></img>
                    </header>

                    <main className="content">
                      <h1 id='tittle'>Welcome to Smart</h1>
                      <h2 id='subTittle'>I am glad you are here!</h2> 
                        
                      <div className="menu">
                        <button className='btnModal' onClick={() => setOpenModal(1)}>Calculator</button>
                        <button className='btnModal'>BMI</button>
                        <button className='btnModal'>Dollars to cent</button>
                        <button className='btnModal'>Seconds to years</button>
                        <button className='btnModal'>Stopwatch</button>
                        <button className='btnModal'>Countdown watch</button>
                        <button className='btnModal'>Countup watch</button>
                        <button className='btnModal'>Weather app</button>
                        <button className='btnModal'>Random number generator</button>
                      </div>
                    </main>

                      <footer id='footerMessage'>
                        <h2>I was made to make your life a little easier</h2> 
                      </footer>
                    </div>

          }
    }

  return(
    <>
      {ModalVerification()}
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import '/src/styles/calculator.css'
import Modal from "react-modal"
import ModalVerification from './App';

export default function Calculator(openModal){

    const [teste, setTeste] = useState(openModal)
    return(
    <Modal 
        isOpen={teste}
        className="contentCalc"
    >
        <button onClick={() => setTeste(0)} className='btnBackToMenu'>botao</button>
      <main className='calculator'>
        <div className="display">
          <div className="operator">=</div>
            <div className="math">
              <div className="lastMath">Histórico de contas</div>
              <div className="actualMath">0</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className="keyboard">
        <button className='btnBlackBoard' id='CE'>CE</button>
        <button className='btnBlackBoard'>C</button>
        <button className='btnBlackBoard'><img src='src/assets/Percent.svg'></img></button>
        <button className='btnBlueBoard'><img src='src/assets/Divide.svg'></img></button>
        <button className='btnBlackBoard'>7</button>
        <button className='btnBlackBoard'>8</button>
        <button className='btnBlackBoard'>9</button>
        <button className='btnBlueBoard' style={{paddingBottom: "7px"}}>x</button>
        <button className='btnBlackBoard'>4</button>
        <button className='btnBlackBoard'>5</button>
        <button className='btnBlackBoard'>6</button>
        <button className='btnBlueBoard'>-</button>
        <button className='btnBlackBoard'>1</button>
        <button className='btnBlackBoard'>2</button>
        <button className='btnBlackBoard'>3</button>
        <button className='btnBlueBoard'>+</button>
        <button className='btnBlackBoard'><img src='src/assets/PlusMinus.svg'></img></button>
        <button className='btnBlackBoard'>0</button>
        <button className='btnBlackBoard'>,</button>
        <button className='btnRedBoard'>=</button>
        </div>
      </main>
    </Modal>
    )
}
```

Comment: O exemplo mostrado na pergunta apresenta muito ruído. Seria melhor [edit] a pergunta e trocar o código por um [mcve] mais enxuto que mostrasse apenas os elementos necessários para reproduzir a dinâmica do problema, sem mostrar o não é relevante para a pergunta. Por exemplo, com exceção a `<button className='btnModal' onClick={() => setOpenModal(1)}>Calculator</button>` e `<button onClick={() => setTeste(0)} className='btnBackToMenu'>botao</button>` todos os outros botões são desnecessários dentro do contexto do problema, a presença de `<header>` e `<footer>` também são desnecessários.

Answer (score 0):

Seu código está um pouco bagunçado, mas dá pra resolver.
Você tem que passar para o componente Calculator o openModal e setOpenModal.
Dentro de calculator, você desestrutura props, e exibe ele de acordo com o estado. No botão dentro do modal, você coloca o onClick com o setOpenModal.
Ficaria algo mais ou menos assim

```
function App(){
  const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState(false)
  
  return (
    ...restante da logica
    <Calculator isOpen={openModal} setOpen={setOpenModal} />
  )
}

export default Calculator(props) {
  const {isOpen, setOpen} = props

  return (
    <Modal 
        isOpen={isOpen}
        className="contentCalc"
    >
        <button onClick={() => setOpen(false)}>Fechar modal</button>
    ...restante da logica
    </Modal>
  )
}
```